# Issue with selenium.webdriver click function using find_elements(By.XPATH,

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have the following code that I am trying to get to click a search button to perform but it fails

search_btn = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
"//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]")
'''
search_btn = self.driver.find_elements(
By.XPATH, "//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]").click()
time.sleep(4)
search_btn.click()
time.sleep(5)
'''
Run Output
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61167/devtools/browser/df335e5f-a2eb-4dfd-a517-61d5dd740b93
[10800:16740:0211/120847.451:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(227)] START: ReportBluetoothAvailability(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[10800:16740:0211/120847.451:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] END: ReportBluetoothAvailability()
[10800:16740:0211/120847.452:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(235)] START: GetDefaultBrowser(). If you don't see the END: message, this is crbug.com/1216328.
[10800:18164:0211/120847.460:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [12:08:47.460] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[10800:18164:0211/120847.468:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [12:08:47.468] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1049 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[10800:16740:0211/120847.470:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(239)] END: GetDefaultBrowser()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:!!!Angela\Paid screen scraper\data scraping\data scraping\my_ui_scrapy12.py", line 278, in show_page
By.XPATH, "//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]").click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'

Comment: I don't see any `click()` in your code, as per the error you are seeing.

Comment: Sorry missed a line   
        search_btn = self.driver.find_elements(
            By.XPATH, "//*[@id='viewContainer']/app-listing-container/app-search-container/app-search-form-container/form/div[3]/button[2]").click()
        time.sleep(4)
        search_btn.click()
        time.sleep(5)